# Search against a virtual attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I'm trying to create full text search on an Event model.
The model contains a country_code field where the country code is stored;
I want to be able to search by country directly by typing the country name, let's say France instead of Fr.

My scope looks like this:

```
pg_search_scope :full_search, against: [:name, :city, :country], associated_against: {
    event_type: [:name],
    dance_types: [:name]
  }
```

I have a country method

```
def country
  return '' if country_code.blank?
  country = ISO3166::Country[country_code]
  (country.translations[I18n.locale.to_s] || country.name) unless country.nil?
end
```

Unfortunately calling my search scope produces the following error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column
>   events.country does not exist.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run your migrations properly?  It appears your database doesn't even have a country field, so no wonder it isn't able to search it.

```
$ rake db:migrate VERSION=0
$ rake db:migrate
```

You also might not have linked the tables properly in your models.  It's hard to tell without all of the details but this looks fishy `column events.country`

Events should be singular, and country should probably be an id field like `column event.country_id`. Maybe you haven't joined the tables properly in their models, or your migrations might be missing proper id fields.

```
# models/events.rb
has_one :country

# models/country.rb
belongs_to :event
```

If that isn't the answer, we need more information about your migrations for country and events.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
My Event model doesn't have a country field by a country_code field. 
I'm using the gem country_select so I don't need to store the complete country name or have a seperate table for countries. That's why I only have a country  contry_code field.
The country method's role is to return the country name for a given country_code